# Java8 lambda for checking two conditions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type, functional-interface

I have the following code snippet which I would try to change to the lambda function.

```
if(catList != null && catList.size() > 0) {
    animalType = AnimalType.CAT;
    HttpEntity<List<?>> request = new HttpEntity<>(catList, headers);
    response = restTemplate.postForObject(apiUrl, request, String.class);
} else if(dogList != null && dogList.size() > 0) {
    animalType = AnimalType.DOG;
} else {
    return;
}
```

Somehow I have written like as shown below, but don't know to incorporate the **dogList** checking the condition

```
Optional.of(catList) 
    .map(catList -> {
        ....
    })
    .orElse(return); //<------ THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: what is the signature of the resource/service method that you're using? Does it expect the various lists and either of them would be `null` is a must?

Comment: @Naman its a void function....I use `response` later for some other business logic within the same function

Comment: Would actually be better if you can update the question with the method and entities that are dealt with in the code segment shared by you.

Comment: stop shoehorning everything into optionals (which btw mostly designed for using as a clearer return type in your api) and lambdas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an other `Optional` inside of the first `Optional`

```
Optional o = Optional.of(catList) 
                     .map(catList -> ...)
                     .orElse(Optional.of(dogList)
                                     .map(dogList -> ...));
```

Or other method using `Stream` if you can make the call to the service generic enough

Or other method using `Stream#of`

It will basically go through both lists, find the first that is not null (but you can add other conditions to your filter if you want) and apply the generic call to service.

```
Optional o = Stream.of(catList, dogList)
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull /*or other condition if you want*/)
                   .findFirst()
                   .map(list -> /*generic call to service*/);
```

And invoke it this way

```
if (!o.isPresent()) return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to return to branch out of a control flow block and exit the method if both `catList` or `dogList` condition is not matching

Comment: @AlexMan I modified the answer, I'm afraid it's not possible in a single chain of method invocation

Comment: also how do we set the `animalType` in the second option using `Stream.of`

Comment: @AlexMan By making the method generic. For example, `if (list.get(0) instanceof Dog) animalType = AnimalType.DOG;`

Comment: in that case I think the first option is better right

Comment: @AlexMan Yes I'd prefer the first option if only for two lists, if more lists can come, then I'd choose the second one and refactor my code

Comment: I am getting an exception when I use the first option like this `Error:(40, 21) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that java.util.Optional<U> conforms to com.example.demo.Cat`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194009/discussion-between-yassin-hajaj-and-alex-man).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to exit a method using the `Optional` or any other class without either explicitly invoking `return` or throwing an exception. Usage of `return` inside a lambda expression is understood within the scope of the method implemented of the functional interface, hence there is no chance to do as your shown code.

There are basically two ways to achieve the desired behavior and keep Java language compliance.

1. Use `return` *after* obtaining a definitive result from `Optional`.

   Here I might repeat an existing answer, but the best you can do is:

   ```
   Optional<MyObject> optional = Optional.of(catList) 
       .map(catList -> new HttpEntity<>(catList, headers))
       .map(httpEntity -> restTemplate.postForObject(apiUrl, request, String.class));

   if (!optional.isPresent()) { return; }           // here the method execution is terminated
   ```

   Checking against `null` or an [Null Object](https://dzone.com/articles/null-object-pattern-in-java) might be a way to go as well.
2. Throw an exception using the [`Optional::orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) allows the method terminates the method and throws an `Exception`. Unfortunately, it obliges an upper layer with a need to handle it or rethrow).

   ```
   MyObject myObject = Optional.of(catList) 
       .map(catList -> new HttpEntity<>(catList, headers))
       .map(httpEntity -> restTemplate.postForObject(apiUrl, request, String.class))
       .orElseThrow(MyObjectException::new);        // here the method execution is terminated
   ```

If the return parameter of the method is not `void`, the `Optional` might be used for the return type definition. The `null` check (or again a [Null Object](https://dzone.com/articles/null-object-pattern-in-java) is a way) might be used there is the method called at:

```
 return Optional.of(catList) 
        .map(catList -> new HttpEntity<>(catList, headers))
        .map(httpEntity -> restTemplate.postForObject(apiUrl, request, String.class))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: But how abt the `dogList` and the `animalType`

Comment: I am trying to create a generic lambda function for handling both catList and dogList instead of duplicating the logic